# My while loop conditions aren't evaluating them as I'm expecting

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an input validation function that checks to see if cin fails (this works fine) and I'm trying to also make it check to see if it's within the min max range that I pass by variable to the function.

I've already tried messing around with different conditions and evaluating it by hand but it seems that either I'm missing some small minutia of the while loop or something total different.

```
void isValid(int &value, std::string message, int min, int max) {
    while(((std::cout << message) && !(std::cin >> value)) && ((value >= min) && (value <= max))) {
        std::cout << "Error with input" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n'); }
```

I expect the output of isValid(-1, "Enter the test score: ", 0, 100) to keep asking for a valid input, but it accepts it as is.

Comment: Try to rephrase your logical condition in plain English and see if this makes sense to you: while the extraction operation fails ***AND*** the extracted value is greater than the minimum value ***AND*** it is less than the maximum value ***THEN*** it is not valid and must be reentered. Does this make sense to you? If it's greater than the minimum and less than the maximum it is ***INVALID*** (even ignoring all the other things)??? As Mr. Spock would say: this is illogical. You need to think about what it means to have invalid input here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think I'm following you. Should I wait till I have a valid input and then have another while loop that just checks if its within the min max?

Comment: No, what you should do is write out the loop condition in plain English, so that it make sense to you, when it is strictly comprised of plain English words. Only when the end results make perfect sense, you take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do too much in the loop conditional. Evidence of this is the fact that you -- the author, and thus the person most likely to understand the code at a glance -- have become confused about the boolean logic.

To make the logic simpler, easier to read, and correct, we can apply the principle of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to split the code into two pieces: one responsible for acquiring the input, and the other responsible for handling what happens if that fails:

```
// returns true if a valid value entered, false if invalid or I/O error
bool getInput(int& value, const std::string& message, int min, int max) {
    if (!(std::cout << message)) return false;
    if (!(std::cin >> value)) return false;
    return value >= min && value <= max;
}

void getValidInput(int& value, std::string message, int min, int max) {
    while (!getInput(value, message, min, max)) {
        std::cout << "Error with input" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n'); }
    }
}
```

Retrying if `std::cout` has an error is dubious; retrying is unlikely to result in success and it probably means something is very wrong with your program. You might consider throwing an exception here instead.